# How to segment text images using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, ocr, pattern-recognition

It's part of the process of OCR,which is :

How to segment the sentences into words,and then characters?

What's the candidate algorithm for this task?

Answer (score 1):

First, NIST (Nat'l Institutes of Standards and Tech.) published a [protocol](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cil/nist-ocr.txt)  known as the ***NIST Form-Based Handwriting Recognition System*** about 15 years ago for the this exact question--i.e., extracting and preparing text-as-image data for input to machine learning algorithms for OCR. Members of this group at NIST also published a number of [papers](http://www.itl.nist.gov/iad/894.03/pubs.html) on this System.

The performance of their classifier was demonstrated by data also published with the algorithm (the "NIST Handwriting Sample Forms.")

Each of the half-dozen or so OCR data sets i have downloaded and used have referenced the data extraction/preparation protocol used by NIST to prepare the data for input to their algorithm.  In particular, i am pretty sure this is the methodology relied on to prepare the Boston University Handwritten Digit Database, which is regarded as benchmark reference data for OCR.

So if the NIST protocol is not a genuine standard at least it's a proven methodology to prepare text-as-image for input to an OCR algorithm. I would suggest starting there, and using that protocol to prepare your data unless you have a good reason not to.

In sum, the NIST data was prepared by extracting 32-bit x 32 bit normalized bitmaps directly from a pre-printed form.

Here's an example:

00000000000001100111100000000000
00000000000111111111111111000000
00000000011111111111111111110000
00000000011111111111111111110000
00000000011111111101000001100000
00000000011111110000000000000000
00000000111100000000000000000000
00000001111100000000000000000000
00000001111100011110000000000000
00000001111100011111000000000000
00000001111111111111111000000000
00000001111111111111111000000000
00000001111111111111111110000000
00000001111111111111111100000000
00000001111111100011111110000000
00000001111110000001111110000000
00000001111100000000111110000000
00000001111000000000111110000000
00000000000000000000001111000000
00000000000000000000001111000000
00000000000000000000011110000000
00000000000000000000011110000000
00000000000000000000111110000000
00000000000000000001111100000000
00000000001110000001111100000000
00000000001110000011111100000000
00000000001111101111111000000000
00000000011111111111100000000000
00000000011111111111000000000000
00000000011111111110000000000000
00000000001111111000000000000000
00000000000010000000000000000000

I believe that the BU data-prep technique subsumes the NIST technique but added a few steps at the end, not with higher fidelity in mind but to reduce file size. In particular, the BU group:

- began with the 32 x 32 bitmaps; then
- divided each 32 x 32 bitmap into
  non-overlapping blocks of 4x4;
- Next, they counted the number of
  activated pixels in each block ("1"
  is activated; "0" is not);
- the result is an 8 x 8 input matrix
  in which each element is an integer (0-16)

Comment: No,the input is an image with sentence on it,I want to split it into images with a single word,and then split into images with a single character.

Comment: I can't find any implementation details in your answer:(

Comment: i'll edit my answer this evening, so that it provides a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 1):

As a first pass:

- process the text into lines
- process a line into segments (connected parts)
- find the largest white band that can be placed between each pair of segments.
- look at the sequence of widths and select "large" widths as white space.
- everything between white space is a word.

Now all you need a a good enough definition of "large".

Comment: But space based solution won't work well with CJK characters:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters

Comment: In that case, OCR a few chars in isolation and take a guess at the alphabet. If it's English, do the above, if not do something else.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the image-processing toolbox in matlab.

To distinguish text in an image. You might want to follow:

1. Grayscale  (speeds up things greatly).
2. Contrast enhancement.
3. Erode the image lightly to remove noise (scratches/blips)
4. Dilation (heavy).
5. Edge-Detection ( or ROI calculation).

With Trial-and-error, you'll get the proper coefficients such that the image you obtain after **5th step** will contain convex regions surrounding each letter/word/line/paragraph.

**NOTE:**

1. Essentially the more you dilate, the larger element you get. i.e. least dilation would be useful in identifying letters, whereas comparitively high dilation would be needed to identify lines and paragraphs.
2. [Online ImgProc MATLAB docs](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/)

Check out the "Examples in Documentation" section in the online docs or refer to the image-processing toolbox documentation in Matlab Help menu.

The examples given there will guide you to the proper functions to call and their various formats.

[Sample CODE (not mine)](http://www.ele.uri.edu/~hansenj/projects/ele585/OCR/)

Comment: There can be multiple contour components after your **STEP 5**,how to deal with them?

Comment: @CVS,It's not a contour based solution.

Comment: Someone has posted a similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789527/ocr-convert-edge-into-a-vector-path

Comment: But at some stage, U would have to start implementing a system to identify & store image patterns as particular characters. Also follow this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789527/ocr-convert-edge-into-a-vector-path

Comment: The key here is how to process the **multiple** chaincode,I've commented on your post.

Comment: U know what would be great? If U could actually take the one extra keystroke necessary to transform "U" to "you."

Answer (score 0):

for finding binary sequence like 101000000000000000010000001
detect sequence 0000,0001,001,01,1